# Dynamic Cell Address in a particular cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, excel-2013, excel-2011

I have a query.

Can i get a cell id of the active cell in excel.

Suppose my current active cell by cursor is A6 , in some particlar cell , say A1 it should say A6.

Next time when i keep cursor on A10, value in the above particular cell A1 should automatically change to A10.

Awaiting for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any from following approaches:

1) you can create an UDF

```
Function getActiveCellAddr() As String
    Application.Volatile True
    getActiveCellAddr = ActiveCell.Address
End Function
```

and then call it in `A1` cell: `=getActiveCellAddr()`

2) you can use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event in the `Sheet module`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A1") = Target.Address
End Sub
```

this code changes content of `A1` each time new cell is selected.

**Note:** Both approaches works with cells in single sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this macro in Selection change Event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Cells(1, 1).Value = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```